# Jquery - Replace Variables

Tags: jquery

I'm looking to create a jQuery script that will replace an html variable if and only if it is inside a certain div. I'd like it to do this for each PostID though.

Each variable is unique depending on the post id.

Example:

```
<div class="[PostID]">
<div class="special">
<div class="container">
(Variable 1 has been replaced by variable 2 here due to the Special class)
[Variable 2]
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

I created a quick script but the problem I have is that when the first variable 2 is replaced, that is also the variable that is used to replace the following special classes. They aren't using their own variable.

Sorry if this is confusing.

Thank you.

Comment: Can you show an actual expected-input, and expected-output from using this script? And what script did you try using? Show us what you've worked with, please. And a live demo, at [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/), or similar, would be extremely helpful! And welcome to Stack Overflow; kudos on, and +1 for, formatting your code correctly in the first instance! =)

Comment: Do you mean that it's only replacing once?

Comment: `<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
   $(".special .container").html($(".container").html().replace('[Variable1]','[Variable2]'));
   });
  </script>` Pretty new at jQuery so this is probably awfully coded. Yes @SmokeyPHP it is only replacing once, instead of for each post. I'm not sure how to add in the PostID and make it check for each PostID class.

Comment: Where does the `.container` class element appear in your HTML (it's *not* in your posted HTML). Will the `special` class be consistent in relation to the changing `[PostID]` element and the `div`s of class `main`? What relation does the `[PostID]` have on the variables you're replacing? Please, show us your actual (representative) input to the script and the desired output *from* the script. And please, when showing code, edit your question to include code in the question, not in comments, where it's (more or less) illegible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could iterate over the containers, replacing vars in one at a time with something like this:

```
$('.special').each(function(){
  $(this).find('.container').html().replace(/V1/g,'V2');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

For a global replace you can use the following regular expression method:

```
string.replace(/\[variable1\]/g,'[variable2]');
```